# ¿Por qué no inserta todas las fechas de un Excel a la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando crear un sistema donde importe datos de un archivo excel a mi base de datos, pero no se insertan bien las fechas. Me salen fechas que no existen y faltan fechas. La tabla donde se insertan los datos tiene esta estructura:

```sql
  CREATE TABLE `nueva_prueba` (
  `IdAsistencia` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `fechaAsistencia` date NOT NULL,
  `horaAsistencia` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `relaUsuario` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `relaEdificio` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `detalle` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `justificante` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` longblob NOT NULL,
  `turno` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `arcna` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Y mi código de funcionamiento del programa seria este:

```php
<select name="edificio" id="Articulo" class="form-control">
        <?php 
        $rows = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `edificio_lector`");
        foreach ($rows as $row){
            echo "<option value=".$row["Id_edificio"].">".$row["descripcion"]."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <input class="form-control" style="background-color:#d3d3d3;" type="file" name="excel" required value="">
     
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="import">Importar</button>

        <?php

        $message = 0;
        if(isset($_POST["import"])){
            $edificio = $_POST['edificio'];
            $fileName = $_FILES["excel"]["name"];
            $fileExtension = explode('.', $fileName);
      $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileExtension));
            $newFileName = date("Y.m.d") . " - " . date("h.i.sa") . "." . $fileExtension;

            $targetDirectory = "uploads/" . $newFileName;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], $targetDirectory);

            error_reporting(0);
            ini_set('display_errors', 0);

            require 'excelReader/excel_reader2.php';
            require 'excelReader/SpreadsheetReader.php';

            $reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetDirectory);
            foreach($reader as $key => $row){
                /*$name = $row[0];
                $age = $row[2];
                $country = $row[0];
                $hora = $row[3];*/
                $id = $row[0];
            //  echo var_dump($id);
                $country = $row[1];
                //$edificio = 1;
                $dateString = strip_tags($country);

                $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $dateString);

                // Obtener el año actual
                $currentYear = intval(date('Y'));
                
                if ($dateTime !== false) {
                    $year = intval($dateTime->format('Y'));
                
                    // Ajustar manualmente el año si es menor que 69
                    if ($year < 69) {
                        $year += 2000;
                    } elseif ($year >= 69 && $year <= 99) {
                        $year += 1900;
                    }
                
                    // Establecer la fecha con el año ajustado
                    $dateTime->setDate($year, intval($dateTime->format('m')), intval($dateTime->format('d')));
                    $date = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
                    $time = $dateTime->format('H:i');
                } else {
                    // Manejo del caso en el que no se pueda convertir la fecha correctamente
                    $date = ''; // O cualquier valor predeterminado que desees asignar
                    $time = ''; // O cualquier valor predeterminado que desees asignar  AND Rela_edificio= '$edificio'
                }

                $buscarUsuario = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuariosistma_lector WHERE Rela_lector='$id' AND Rela_edificio= '$edificio' ");
                foreach($buscarUsuario as $b){
                    $idUser = $b['Rela_usuario'];
                    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM nueva_prueba WHERE fechaAsistencia = '$date' AND horaAsistencia = '$time' and relaUsuario='$idUser'");

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
                        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO nueva_prueba VALUES( '', '$date', '$time', '$idUser', '$edificio', '','','','','')");
                        $message = $message + 1;
        
                    }

                }
            
            }
     echo
            "
            
            <script>
        
            alert('Registros insertados');
            document.location.href = '';
            </script>
            ";
            
        }   
        
        ?>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que inserte correctamente las fechas?

Comment: Hola Goutos. ¿Podrías agregar en tu pregunta un ejemplo del archivo Excel? Es para ver como estan los datos en el archivo. A modo de comentario, tu programa es suseptible a [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php) y hackeo via upload de archivos ejecutables.

Comment: 7   -  8/11/2021 12:52 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 0    esto es una fila
                                                                                                                          
 2   - 8/11/2021 12:54 - 1 - 1 -  1 - 0 y esto es otra fila

asi seria mi archivo excel